# Does wordpress mail functionality works if I change MX records?

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I got a cPanel account from my godaddy, and changed the MX records to work with google apps (domain is pointing to said panel). I installed Wordpress using a 1-click wizard (which means setup should be fine) but Wordpress won't send me mails (not when adding a new wordpress user,  not when using the "contact us" form, etc). Since I'm not familiar with wordpress troubleshooting, I don't know if the problem is because:

1. MX records affect it
2. `mail()` doesn't work at all on cPanel.
3. Something went wrong on the wordpress setup.

To rule the first one out, does MX records affect php `mail()` function?

Comment: The MX Record is and IP Adress of lets say a Domain Name Server which knows on which IP-Adress to send an e-mail on a given name like `gmail@chucknorris.com` . This has nothing to do with wordpress, wordpress setup or mail()

Comment: Did `mail()` work before changing your MX Record to point to google apps? GoDaddy support is the first place you should check.

Answer (score 1):

I believe answer 2 is correct.

WordPress' ability to send email, which is done by your server, is not affected by your MX change. It's dependent on whether or not your server has an ability/rights to send email.

cPanel and the server's ability to send email are not the same thing.